# Seemingly cannot install anything in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I think I have somehow rigged my anaconda environment. 
Using anaconda prompt I fail to install anything. The following code is what I get as a report. 
I'm kinda new to programming, so my question could be stupid. 
I still kindly ask you for help, as I'm struggling with this for several hours already.

The error report is rather lengthy. I think the core information is that:

```
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 414, in send
        raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http://proxy.yourorg.org:port
```

The program fails to parse this http-thing twice.

Can anybody help?

Comment: first of all, don't worry about your questions. questions are to be asked ;). If you have put enough effort to think and work on any question and couldn't answer it then it deserves asking! Coming to your question it is explained in detail here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8862 I hope it helps.

Comment: What led to that error?

Comment: The Link Anya Samadi provided solved it. 
I conclude that there somehow was a configuration in the .condarc.py file which made python want to use somekind of dysfunctional proxy. 
I never actively changed that file. So I don't know why it was flawed.